# Why was file writer discontinued?

Tags: javascript, w3c

It appears that the [FileWriter interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface) which was originaly used to implement [saveAs](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) is discontinued and probably deprecated.
All documentation was gone before I even noticed it existed.

Was there security issues with this interface? I admit that wouldn't suprise me.

What was it capable of?

Comment: Check the [list archives](http://www.w3.org/Search/Mail/Public/search?type-index=public-webapps&index-type=t&keywords=FileWriter&search=Search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the old specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-file-writer-api-20101026/

This was removed likely because of the huge security risks of allowing websites to write to disk. It was mostly replaced with the ability to use localstorage and local sql. This prevented most malicious files from entering the system and sandboxed the whole idea of needing to store data on a system.

Comment: And what was to relation to the saveAs function?

Comment: saveAs was a method that allows you to save a file somewhere on the system. The original specification was scrapped before full details of this was available the the remaining browser implementations based on that repository are still usable in [development experiements](http://www.noupe.com/webdev/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html)

Comment: The best way to put it is that the filesystem api wasn't secure enough and has been replaced by browser specific implementations. For instance, Chrome allows you to access the filesystem as a chrome app given you ask permission.

Comment: This is so disappointing